# RegEx optional group with optional sub-group

Tags: regex

I have a set of strings with fairly inconsistent naming, that should be structured enough to be divided into groups though.

Here's an excerpt:

```
test test 1970-2020 w15.txt
test 1970-2020 w15.csv
test  1990-99 q1 .txt
test 1981 w15 .csv
test test  w15.csv
```

I am trying to extract information by groups (test-name, (year)?, suffix, type) using the following RegEx:

```
(.*)\s+([0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)?\s+)?((w|q)[0-9]+(\s+)?)(\..*)$
```

It works except for the optional group matching the years (interval of year's, single year or no year at all).
What am I missing to make the pattern work?

Here's also a link to RegEx101 for testing:

https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/817

Comment: your first group matches everything, you need to be more specific like `[^0-9]+` or `[ a-z]+`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific and make the content of the year optional

```
^(.*?)\s+((?:\d{4}(?:-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))?)?)\s+([wq][0-9]+)\s*(\.\w+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1** Match 0+ times any char except a newline non greedy
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d{4}(?:-(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))?` Match 4 digits and optionally `-` and 2 or 4 digits
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make the year optional
- `)` Close group 2
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `([wq][0-9]+)` Capture **group 3** Match either `w` or `q` and 1+ digits 0-9
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\.\w+)` Capture **group 4**, match a dot and 1+ word characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8IGwG/1)

Note that `\s` could also match a newline.

Comment: Making the first group non-greedy did the trick. The year is not always either 4 or 2 digits long, that's why I didn't specify the amount of digits. This is the RegEx that fullfilled my needs, in case anyone is interested: (.*?)\s+([0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)?)?(?:\s+)?([wq])([0-9]+)(?:\s+)?(\..*)$